# Drop non-TLS connection on EXIM

Tags: exim, tls, starttls

How to restrict access to EXIM to clients with STARTTLS?  I want to be able to drop non-TLS connections.

Current setup:

```
tls_on_connect_ports = 465
tls_advertise_hosts = *
tls_certificate = /some/file/name
tls_privatekey = /some/file/name
```

Comment: The standard port 465 doesn't use `STARTTLS`; it is defined as being SMTP-over-TLS, in which TLS negotiation is completed before any SMTP protocol data is sent or received.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the next rule to the RCPT ACL:

```
acl_rcpt:
deny ! hosts         =  : +relay_from_hosts
     ! authenticated = *
. . . .
```

That rule deny submission from any non-trusted host without authentication.

Comment: This doesn't really address the situation where the client is doing AUTH without TLS, which is the question if I read it correctly. You need to only advertise auth if tls is active, then the above works. But perhaps auth is not relevant for the question.

Comment: I tried following with no luck.                                                            acl_check_rcpt:
deny  message        = This domain ($sender_address_domain) requires a TLS connection which is not present
      sender_domains = *
      ! encrypted    = *
   
In routers:

tls_router:
  driver = dnslookup
  domains = *
  transport = tls_smtp


In transports:

tls_smtp:
  driver = smtp
  hosts_require_tls = *

Comment: Because of number of characters limit, I will split into two comments

I am trying to secure my EXIM servers , was wondering how I can accomplish the following:

- Restrict email relay to TLS and reject none TLS connections.

- Use port 587 for client TLS connections back to VIP then to servers.

- Restrict mail inflow to port 25 and 465 if possible.

Your response is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Current Setup :

- I do relay by IP and have VIP SSL installed locally on each EXIM server.

- I connect from Linux clients using mailx -S smtp-use-starttls.

- I have tried all settings below and still EXIM relay email without TLS

daemon_smtp_ports          = 25 : 465 : 587
tls_advertise_hosts            = *
tls_on_connect_ports         =      465 : 587


auth_advertise_hosts = localhost : ${if eq{$tls_cipher}{}{no}{*}}
server_advertise_condition = ${if eq{$tls_in_cipher}{}{no}{yes}}
hosts_require_tls = *


acl_check_rcpt:

deny ! hosts         =  : +relay_from_hosts
     ! authenticated = *